# Background-gradient doesn't follow the scrollbar when adding it to the bottom of the div

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to add a white fade to the bottom of a  and seems to work fine at first glance. But when I scroll down I can see this fade isn't at the bottom anymore. Does anyone know why this could happen and how to fix it?

I uploaded 2 images on postimg.cc, so you can see how does it look like:

- [Image 1](https://postimg.cc/tnTmGMjh)
- [Image 2](https://postimg.cc/kVm1g4CM)

```
.details {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    &::-webkit-scrollbar {
        background-color: $c-grey-50;
        width: 0.375rem;
        border-radius: $br-4;
    }
    &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background-color: $c-grey-200;
        border-radius: $br-4;
        transition: $tr-smooth;
    }
    &::before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 20px;
        background: linear-gradient(
            to bottom,
            rgba(255, 255, 255, 0),
            #ffffffda
        );
        z-index: 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try change `position` in before to `fixed` or `sticky`?

Comment: As @Eezo said, `position: sticky; display: block;` will do.

Answer (score 0):

Proper way would be to handle it in `.details` background itself. Use [color stops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient#linear-color-stop) in `linear-gradient`:

```css
body {
  background: skyblue;
}

.details {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  &::-webkit-scrollbar {
    background-color: $c-grey-50;
    width: 0.375rem;
    border-radius: $br-4;
  }
  &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: $c-grey-200;
    border-radius: $br-4;
    transition: $tr-smooth;
  }
  
  background : 
    linear-gradient( 
      to bottom,
      transparent 0 70%,
      white
    );
}
```

```html
<div class="details">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
```